# GWT 2.5.1 in Eclipse 4.2?

Tags: google-plugin-eclipse

I already [posted that question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plugin-eclipse/4Vx_56NT0fQ) in the corresponding [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-plugin-eclipse), but then I saw that questions should rather be asked here.

So I would like to know if a release 2.5.1 of the Google Plugin for Eclipse is planned and if so, when can we expect it ?

Thank you, Joe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK well, it appears the version is already installable via http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2

More info on the [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plugin-eclipse/4Vx_56NT0fQ).

Answer (score 1):

There is going to be release for Google Plugin for Eclipse in about a week. Please look out for it at https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download.

Comment: That is good to know, but I was rather searching for 2.5.1 GWT plugin for Eclipse 4.2 (which was the latest at the moment of my post).